# update nav without reloading

Tags: jquery, dynamic, nav

I'm looking for a simple method to swap the active state (color) of my navigation without a page reload.

1. this should happen when one nav button is pressed. Essentially it should change it's state to active, and change all the other buttons to a non-active state.
2. I'm new to jquery, but it seems like there would have been a simple solution there. If there is I sure haven't come across it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this answer would have been trivial for you to put together yourself, but anyway... [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) will do it.

```
$('nav a').on('click', function() {
  $('nav a')
    .removeClass('active')
    .filter(this)
    .addClass('active');
});
```

CSS

```
a.active {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```